# getElementById where the id changes randomly

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, vba, getelementbyid

I am trying to automate a website login for:

https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/

However the ID of the input textbox changes randomly, is there a way to scan through the code and establish it's current ID?

I have tried using `GetElementsByTagName` but that did not work.

When I use the inspect element it takes me to this line:

It is the **202413237510** that changes randomly of the line of code below.

```
<input name="202413237510" class="form-control" id="202413237510" type="text" value="">
```

The surrounding code below:

```
<form name="moth-search" id="EVL" action="/" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="form-title heading-medium visuallyhidden">Enter the vehicle registration</legend>
            <input name="_csrf_token" type="hidden" value="7A9313B6-6834-04E2-56BE-D6966FFE041F">
                                                                                        <div class="form-group apiary-22453 ddt">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="1700806253">
                        <span>Do not fill this field</span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="1700806253" tabindex="-1" class="form-control" id="1700806253" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group is-on-show tyu-33">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="reg-number">
                        <span>Do not enter anything in this field</span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="reg-number" tabindex="-1" class="form-control" id="reg-number" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group hoth-field it-290">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="202413237510">
                        <span><span class="sr-only">Enter your</span> Registration number (number plate) <span class="sr-only">into this field only</span></span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="202413237510" class="form-control" id="202413237510" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group it-290 salad-box">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="vehicle-manufacturer">
                        <span>This field should be left empty</span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="vehicle-manufacturer" tabindex="-1" class="form-control" id="vehicle-manufacturer" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group keep-hidden isOnshow">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="registration">
                        <span>Do not fill this field</span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="registration" tabindex="-1" class="form-control" id="registration" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
                                                                                        <div class="form-group bee-hive tyu-33">

                    <label class="form-label form-label-bold" for="registration-number">
                        <span>Do not fill this field</span>
                        <span class="form-hint">For example, CU57ABC</span>
                                                </label>

                    <input name="registration-number" tabindex="-1" class="form-control" id="registration-number" type="text" value="">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the VBA you're using now to parse the document html? I can probably show you the regex `name="(\d)*" class="form-control" id="(\d)*"` expression and how to pull the id out

Comment: To get the current id you can try `Set post = HTML.querySelector("input.form-control"): MsgBox post.getAttribute("id")` Here `HTML` being `HTMLDocument` and `post` being `Object`. If I could understand your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show any code so I'm not sure how you're getting at the document. My example uses the IE object from MS Internet Controls and then RegExp object from VBScript Regular Expressions.

You should be able to just pull out the RegExp constant, variables and code to get your id from your document body variable.

This regular expression searches for matching input elements that consist of numbers in the their name - but the trick is it ignores the ones that have `tabindex="-1"` in the definition.

```
Sub ExtractID()

'To use this example you'll need two references
'Open the VBA editor and pull down Tools | References menu
'- select "Microsoft Internet Controls"
'- select "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

Const FIND_NEW_ID       As String = "name=""(\d)*"" class=""form-control"" id=""(\d)*"""

Dim ie          As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim regEx       As New RegExp
Dim idMatches   As MatchCollection
Dim idMatch     As Match

Dim strHTML     As String
Dim strID       As String

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

With ie
    .Navigate "https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/"
    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    strHTML = ie.Document.body.innerHTML
    'Set doc = .Document
    'strHTML = doc.body.innerHTML

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = FIND_NEW_ID
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strHTML) Then
        Set idMatches = regEx.Execute(strHTML)
        If idMatches.Count = 1 Then
            strID = Mid$(idMatches(0).Value, 7) ' remove name from front
            strID = Left$(strID, InStr(strID, """") - 1) ' pull ID from double quotes
            MsgBox "Found ID: " & strID
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Going to Work - we found multiples"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox ("No ID Found")
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a great site for testing regular expressions against your HTML docs

Comment: Thanks dbmitch, not familiar with vbscript so will have to go off and try and workout exactly what your code is doing, it works  treat but don't like not knowing the how.

Comment: Glad it works for you. Check the code for VBA comments.As for Regular Expressions that can be a life long learning experience, but yours was pretty simple - it just looks for that input line and makes it non-specific by limiting the `id` and `name` to any amount of numbers `(\d)*` enclosed by quotes